# jquery - image load after .show()

Tags: jquery, html, image

I'm trying to get the dimensions of an image after a div is shown.

What I got:

**JQUERY**:

```
$("body").on("click", ".more-info", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".component-alt-main").show(0, function() {
        $(this).find(".component-img").each(function() {
            $(this).find("img").on("load", function() {
                console.log("A")
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="component-alt-main"> <!-- This has display none -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="components">
            <h3>Versiones alternativas</h3>
            <div class="component-container">
                <div class="component">
                    <div class="component-img">
                        <img src="modulos/topbar/topbar-01b_ios@2x.png">
                    </div>
                    <p class="title">Topbar principal <b>simple</b></p>
                    <div class="component-text">
                        <p>
                            Puede darse el caso de que tengamos una sección dónde sólo aplique el título.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="component">
                    <div class="component-img">
                        <img src="modulos/topbar/topbar-01c_ios@2x.png">
                    </div>
                    <p class="title">Topbar principal <b>simple</b></p>
                    <div class="component-text">
                        <p>
                            Variable de un botón pulsable en el lateral derecho. No puede haber más de uno.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get that `console.log()` after I click a button (`.more-info`), but it's not entering. I don't know if it's because the images are already loaded (even though `.component-alt-main` is with `display: none;`). But if I try to get those image before the .show(), the `width` of them are 0 obviously.

There's something wrong with the code above?

**PS:**

I'm asking this because later on I must use AJAX to resize the images once they are loaded.

**PSS:***

The console.log placed on `.each()` works.

Comment: i cound't see .more-info class in your code?

Comment: @GaneshPutta It's not, it's just an anchor that shows `.component-alt-main` div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as
>     before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

So as you can see it's not a reliable way to use `load` on `img` tag. You may try loading the image using AJAX [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method and in the `complete` handler do you work. Alternatively read the img dimensions in server side code and pass it as data attributes on `img` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @Vivek Athalye's answer. This method might also help you in getting the width and height properties for the (sample) images.

```html
<body>
<div class="component-alt-main"> <!-- This has display none -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="components">
            <h3>Versiones alternativas</h3>
            <div class="component-container">
                <div class="component">
                    <div class="component-img">
                        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <p class="title">Topbar principal <b>simple</b></p>
                    <div class="component-text">
                        <p>
                            Puede darse el caso de que tengamos una sección dónde sólo aplique el título.
                        </p>
                    </div>
     <input class="more-info" type="button" value="Get Dimensions"/>
                </div>
                <div class="component">
                    <div class="component-img">
                        <img src="http://www.bajiroo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/most-disturbing-photoshopped-of-the-month-pics-images-photos-pictures-bajiroo-31.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <p class="title">Topbar principal <b>simple</b></p>
                    <div class="component-text">
                        <p>
                            Variable de un botón pulsable en el lateral derecho. No puede haber más de uno.
                        </p>
                    </div>
     <input class="more-info" type="button" value="Get Dimensions"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$("body").on("click", ".more-info", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    $(".component-alt-main").show(0, function() {
        $(this).find(".component-img").each(function() {
            $(this).find("img").each(function () {
   
 
   console.log("width: " + this.clientWidth + " and Height: "+this.clientHeight);
   
});
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```